# Do 'children' and 'minors' mean the same thing?

Tags: support, tagging

I have seen the two words being used over and over again here but don't know whether they are synonyms of each other or not. The Usage guides for the two tags seem not to help very much:

[children](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/children) x232

> Travel with children of all ages from infants to toddlers to teenagers.

[minors](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minors) x69

> Questions about people younger than the age of adulthood, generally younger than 18 to 20 years old.

Can somebody elaborate about the 'age' part?

Created by the same user, presumably some difference was intended.

Selecting for Google's preferred definition sets:

*child*: a young human being below the age of puberty or below the legal age of majority.

*minor*: a person under the age of full legal responsibility.

Answer (score 9):

In a nutshell, the way I understand it; the `children` tag is for questions about dealing *with* children, and issues faced *due to* children. The `minors` tag probably has more to do with issues that *affect* people under 18, be that legally or culturally.

Example question for `children` tag:

> Q: I will be travelling to Venice, Italy for a 2 week holiday, and would like to know if there are any restaurants that provide customers with ball gags to shut my god damn nephew up.

Example question for `minors` tag:

> Q: I am a 16 year old who will be travelling to Venice, Italy for 2 weeks to see my annoying Uncle. Will the Immigration officer ask me who I'll be staying with?

Comment: Disclaimer: These questions are satirical, grossly oversimplified examples. I'm not responsible if you post them and get downvoted to hell.

Comment: That's exactly how I always understood these tags.

Answer (score 3):

There is a good amount of overlap in the way [children](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/children) and [minors](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minors) are currently used, but the latter seem to be focused on things an older child is or isn't allowed to do, whereas the former include many more questions about caring for younger and more dependent children. I think this reflects a real distinction in how we use those terms conversationally: *minor* is a term defining a legal status, whereas *child* is a social term referring to a familial relationship or to a physically immature person.

The distinctions between older children (*adolescents*, *teenagers*, *young adults*, etc.) and younger children, and infants and toddlers from their older siblings, are also reflected in regulations and company policies. An airline, for a well-known example, is likely to have different rules and policies for newborn through age 2, ages 3 to 5, ages 6 to 12, and ages 12 to 17; it is not as simple as *adulthood* / *childhood* or *majority* / *minority*.

Ultimately, I think the *minors* tag remains useful; it's a term that has implications not only for unaccompanied minors policies but for things like drinking age, consent laws, and insurance coverage. But I think [children](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/children) is probably too broadly scoped at present. With 232 questions, there is probably some room for subdivision.

Answer (score -2):

My suggestion is to change the usage guide...

[children](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/children)

> For issues concerning travelers under the age of 18, *except for visa and immigration questions*

[minors](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minors)

> For visa and immigration questions about travelers under the age of 18

I think that's the most accurate distinction, as well as the most useful.

And then use [age-limits](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age-limits) for questions that don't fall into either of them.

Comment: [children] to me is questions like "how can I keep my kid relaxed on an airplane". [minors] is then mostly for "what docs do I need to take my kid outside the Schengen area"

Comment: @pnuts good point about [age-limits], A updated

Comment: We have a number of questions about renting a hotel room while you are underage - I think that should have [minors], not [children]. It's not just visa and immigration. Something about legal rights and responsibilities might be relevant in a tag description. But not a topic area.